# Calculate stock trading position for buy and take profit in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm currently developing a trading diary. There are many positions having multiple buy and take profit transactions. Here's a sample:

- The initial position size is 50 @20 USD
- One week later, we sell 15 @22 USD
- Another 2 weeks later we sell again 15 @23 USD
- One week later, a pullback comes into the price so we buy another 25 @21 USD
- One week later, we sell again 20 @23 USD
- Another 4 weeks later we sell 25 shares @25 USD

One business rule is the following: To get the actual P/L calculation, the "last buy point" must always be used as long as we have shares in place.

In this case, we can deduct 2 x 15 Shares (330 USD + 345 USD) from the initial 50 shares (1k USD). After buying 25 shares (after the pullback), we first have to deduct 20 remaining shares (460 USD) from the initial position (50 shares for 1k USD). For the last sell point of 25 shares (625 USD) we have to use the second buy point of 25 shares @21 USD (525 USD).

Any help is appreciated.

Krgds
Sascha

Comment: Please read [ask].  WHat you have posted is a set of requirements, not a question.  Please show a [mcve], and what specific problem you are having.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag with the database you are using.